# uilabel dynamic height into uiscrollview not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a problem with one of my viewcontrollers, the detailViewController that contains the next ui elements:

```
1 scroll view
2 image views
2 labels
```

the layout in the storyboard is

[image]

and the constraints added are:

[image]

the label 2 is the label that should be resizing automatically.

the label 2 lines in the the attributes inspector is set to 0

and the relation in the height constraint is set to

```
Greater than or Equal
```

finally the result is

[image]

but the text shown in the label 2 is not complete and the scrolling is not working.

Comment: What is the compression resistance?

Comment: sorry @Wain where can I find the compression resistance?

Comment: Underneath the layouts in interface builder

Comment: horizontal: 750 and vertical:750

Comment: And the height constraint you refer to as greater than or equal to is set at the height of 1 line with a priority of 1000? Try the compression at 1000

Comment: I've set the compression resistance of the dynamic label to 1000 instead of 750 but it doesn't works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102170/discussion-between-edu-and-wain).